# How make modal dialog covering app page with with horizontal scrolling?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

Basing on tailwindcss 2 modal example https://alpinetoolbox.com/examples/modal
I use modal dialog in my tailwindcss 2, Alpinejs 2 app and it works for me
except cases when I use a lot of data on the page with horizontal scrolling.
In this case modal dialog covers only visible part of the screen, what is not good.

I tried some ways to set height of modal to full height, like :

```
<!--Overlay-->
<div class="overflow-auto w-full h-full" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" x-show="showModal" :class="{ 'absolute inset-0 z-10 flex items-center justify-center': showModal }">
```

but failed.

Could you please check pen: https://codepen.io/petrogromovo/pen/yLMNVLr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace the position `absolute` with `fixed` on the overlay `div`.

```html
<div 
    class="overflow-auto w-full h-full" 
    style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" 
    x-show="showModal" 
    :class="{ 'fixed inset-0 z-10 flex items-center justify-center': showModal }"
>
```